# Facebook oauth dialog redirect without code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm trying to get the code to use with /oauth/access_token to get the access_token for a facebook app. From what I've read (here and in the facebook dev docs about access token), I have to make a request at that adress :

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=269256053176066&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.outils.ch%2Ffacebook%2Fgroupemutuel%2Fcanevas%2Fadvices%2F&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages

And it should give me back as a get parameter the code to use to generate the access_token. This is where I'm stuck, it redirect me to the facebook app page, but without any code. I've been on this since yesterday and can't figure what I'm missing and dont find any similar post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally find out where was the problem, the page was redirecting automatically to the facebook app page (whitout the code). I was able to find the code with chrome console in network tab.